# setter get mongoose object id before save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is it possible in mongoose to get _id before save in other property setters?

Example i got a field "fileName" and want to make function for setter that will pass fieldName and objectId to other function for processing.

Comment: You could use the `.pre('save')` event hook to accomplish firing an event before a document is saved.

Comment: so lets  say i use pre('save') then process all fields and then next()?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do all the processing you'd need, then call next(). This hook will run every time before a document of that model is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my earlier commment, you could do something like this:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  // do stuff
  next();
});
```

Note: `.pre('save')` hooks don't run on updates such as `update()` or `findOneAndUpdate()`

There is also a `.post('save', function() {})` hook that you can use as well.